# use jquery functions on PHP string

Tags: php, jquery

I'm searching for a php library which i can use like jquery on a php string.
I have a string in php

```
$html = "<html><head></head><body><div><span>test</span></div></body></html>";
```

Now I want to use functions like $("body").find("div span").text();

Is there something like this available?
I know you can solve this with regular expressions but the html -string is more complex than this example so I don't think this is a proper solution.

Already thanks!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pekka said, go on with [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). It's written following jquery syntax.